# Prevent chapter and section being in every page header

Tags: header-footer

I downloaded a nice latex class, but I'm having trouble with one aspect of it - every page's header gets marked with either the chapter name or section name.

[image]

As you can see, it makes the page look really cluttered. The code for the class is [here](https://pastebin.com/b1nr8JtH).  I've tried for a really long time to solve this, but I can't. I searched online and found that some commands containing `mark` have that info, and I've tried commenting out lines containing such commands. Still no luck and could use some help on this - I just want the page numbers to show in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response copied directly from here, using the `fancyhdr` package:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234123/remove-chapter-title-from-header-on-all-pages-latex-book-class

Since the code is in your preamble, you do not need to modify `antiquebook` at all.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{antiquebook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}            % Permits header customization. See header section below.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A very very very very very very very very very long chapter title}
     \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{another very very very very very long section title}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing - if I want the page number at the center of the footer, how should I do it? I tried `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}`  but the page number seems a bit offset to the left or right depending on the page number

Comment: Out of my mind, this might be because `antiquebook` is a book-type class, that has different margin settings for pages on the left and the right. Have you checked if it is centered by adding `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble? This will color the margins on the pages and you can check that.